# Access Hive Metadata using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I am trying to access Hive Metadata using JDBC. I have added all the jar files required in the classpath. I was following the tutorial from here- `https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-JDBC`

After adding all the jar files I tried to wrote a sample program to connect to Hive using Java. When I debug the code, as soon as it hit the below line.

```
Connection con = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://lvsaishdc3in0001.lvs.host.com:10000/
default","", "");
```

I always get this exception. Not sure why is it happening. Can anyone help me how to fix this problem?

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to 
lvsaishdc3in0001.lvs.host.com:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
timed out: connect
```

I started my Hive sever by logging into Putty and passing the hostname.

```
$ bash
bash-3.00$ cd /usr/local/bin
bash-3.00$ hive --service hiveserver
Starting Hive Thrift Server
12/07/03 08:07:11 INFO service.HiveServer: Starting hive server on port 10000
```

Comment: My guess is that there's nothing listening on port 10000 on that server.

Comment: I edited my question by adding how I started Hive Server.

Comment: You might have started Hive server, but apparently that doesn't mean it's listening.  Believe the error.

Comment: ummm, Then what should I do in this case? Any pointers?

Comment: Have you tried running your application locally on the same server where you started Hive?

Comment: @Olaf, Yes I exported the jar and it was the MapReduce program, so it was working fine. Is there any way from the command prompt I can find what is the domain name I need to use and port number to connect to hive?

Comment: Did you have any luck accessing the metadata using the JDBC driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive server is pretty unsecured by itself. It doesn't eve require username/password for authentication. From my experience, the most typical configuration is to start Hive server on the same box as the application, make sure that this box is connected to the Hadoop cluster and to secure this box. This way your connection string is `jdbc:hive://localhost:10000` and the security becomes not your headache, but a headache of your networking folks.

Comment: But it's not localhost as from the Putty I am login to `ares-ingest.vip.host.com` so that is the reason I am confuse. What should be the conenction url.

Comment: Can you start Hive server on ares-ingest.vip.host.com?

Comment: I already started the server and still I am getting the same thing. May be the hostname and port number are not right? Is there any way I can find out from the cmd prompt which host and port number I need to connect to hive server.

Comment: Unless you are doing something VERY special, it's always port 10000 on the localhost. Try doing netstat.

Comment: I am stuck on one more problem in Hive. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588510/count-the-mismatch-and-missing/11588640#11588640](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588510/count-the-mismatch-and-missing/11588640#11588640). I am not sure whether this is possible to do it in hive or not. Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated whether it is possible to do it in hive or not.