# Count the mismatch and missing

Tags: sql, join, group-by, hive

Below is the data in TestingTable1

```
BUYER_ID   |   ITEM_ID         |    CREATED_TIME
-----------+-------------------+------------------------
1345653        110909316904         2012-07-09 21:29:06
1345653        151851771618         2012-07-09 19:57:33
1345653        221065796761         2012-07-09 19:31:48
1345653        400307563710         2012-07-09 18:57:33
1345653        310411560125         2012-07-09 16:09:49
1345653        120945302103         2012-07-09 13:40:23
1345653        261060982989         2012-07-09 09:02:21
```

Below is the data in TestingTable2

```
USER_ID   |   PRODUCT_ID           |    LAST_TIME
-----------+-------------------+-------------------
1345653       110909316904         2012-07-09 21:30:06
1345653       152851771618         2012-07-09 19:57:33
1345653       221065796761         2012-07-09 19:31:48
1345653       400307563710         2012-07-09 18:57:33
```

I need to Compare `TestingTable2` with `TestingTable1` on `BUYER_ID` and `USER_ID`. And I need to find all (basically the count) the missing and mismatch entries in `TestingTable2` after comparing from `TestingTable1`. I created SQL fiddle for this-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d87b2/1

If you run my query in the SQL Fiddle, you will get output as-

```
BUYER_ID    ERROR
1345653       5
```

which is right as last `three` rows from `TestingTable1` is missing in `TestingTable2` and rest `two` are mismatch after comparison from `TestingTable1` on `BUYER_ID` and `USER_ID`.

Now the complicated thing is starting.

**Problem Statement-**

In my current output, I am getting ERROR count as `5`. So if you see first row in both the tables `ITEM_ID` and `PRODUCT_ID` are same but `CREATED_TIME` and `LAST_TIME` is not same, and difference between those two times is of only `1 minute`. So currently I am reporting that as a mismatch, but what I need is that if the difference between them  is within `15 minutes range`, then I don't want to report as an error. So after implementing this feature in my current query, I will be getting error count as 4 because difference is within 15 minute range for the first row.

So how can I implement this feature in my current query? That's my question.

P.S- I am working with Hive and Hive supports sql like syntax. So I think any modification will work in my current query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your SQL Server SQL Fiddle query could be modified as follows and made to work. However, i am not sure if Hive supports datediff

```
SELECT TT.BUYER_ID , COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT testingtable1.buyer_id, testingtable1.item_id, testingtable1.created_time FROM
 testingtable2 RIGHT JOIN testingtable1 
 ON (testingtable1.item_id = testingtable2.product_id 
 AND testingtable1.BUYER_ID = testingtable2.USER_ID 
 AND abs(datediff(mi, testingtable1.created_time,testingtable2.last_time)) <= 15)
 where testingtable2.product_id IS NULL) TT GROUP BY TT.BUYER_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks cravoori, yes it is working in SQL. But when I tried the same thing in HiveQL, it is throwing error at `mi`. And I found this link [http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/date-functions-in-hive.html](http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/date-functions-in-hive.html) in which I can see there is datediff function in Hive also. But how I can modify the same query to work in Hive by using the same function. As currently it is reporting error as `FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: line 10:157 Invalid Table Alias mi`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you help me out here? I am looking for alternate way to do the same thing that you did with your solution you posted above, as it is working fine in SQL Server, so I need some other way to do the same thing, basically an alternate way, I tried putting the date diff condition in where clause but it didn't worked. Any help will be appreciated.